# Outlook API v2.0 refresh token?

Tags: api, outlook, token, msdn, refresh-token

I'm using the outlook api v2.0

I can get the access token and it works great !

My problem is that the access token last only 1 hour and I can't find any documentation to get a refresh token with the v2.0 ...

Someone knows how to proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to request and use the scope "offline_access" then you will also get a refresh token.

Comment: You must write that in a comment, instead of answer.

Comment: Can somebody Add more info on this? is there any api for refresh token to get access token and other tokens?

Comment: Yes please add some info. i am facing same issue.